# Get username from Azure Identity

Tags: c#, azure, authentication

I'm using the new Azure.Identity package (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/identity-readme) in a simple .NET Core console app to log into Azure, e.g.:

```
var credential = new DefaultAzureCredential()
```

Works fine, but now I want to get the name, eMail etc. of the currently logged in user. Has anyone an idea how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could get token with [`GetTokenAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.identity.defaultazurecredential.gettokenasync?view=azure-dotnet) first, then obtain the username(`upn`) of the user by decoding the [access token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens).

```
var credential = new DefaultAzureCredential();
string[] scopes = new string[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
var token = await credential.GetTokenAsync(new Azure.Core.TokenRequestContext(scopes));

var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
var jsonToken = handler.ReadToken(token.Token) as JwtSecurityToken;
var upn = jsonToken.Claims.First(c => c.Type == "upn").Value;
```

Comment: In my particular scenario, there is no "upn" claim in the token. But this approach was still very useful for solving the problem.